# My objects change their shape after rendering

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render a cube animation in blender, but when i preview the render the shape changes, this is it before rendering:

[image: Before]

and after rendering:

[image: After]

sorry for any problems, I'm new to blender stack exchange and blender in general

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: It looks like you have a subdivision surface modifier on your object(s) that is set to 0 subdivisions for viewport, and >0 for render. It looks like you also (may) have a duplicated face on one side of each cube? Not sure if this intentional...